# How to tell if Rails action mailer deliver fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

In my project, I'm using Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 2.1.1. I was reading the [`mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail#getting-error-reports-from-an-email) gem, but wasn't sure how to check if the `deliver` failed (for any reason).

```
result = UserMailer.signup.deliver
if result.action == 'failed' or result.bounced?
    # How can you tell if a deliver has failed?
    # Do stuff here if failed
end
```

Answer (score 13):

As described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html, you can set

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

this way, Rails will raise an error in case the delivery can't take place

Comment: What is the error that is raised? So I can `rescue_from` it

Comment: Derek - I've been looking myself for a list, but can't find it. I would simply catch them all, putting your rescue just around the deliver call

Comment: All the exceptions https://robots.thoughtbot.com/i-accidentally-the-whole-smtp-exception . According to that errors are: (IOError,
  Net::SMTPAuthenticationError
  Net::SMTPServerBusy,
  Net::SMTPUnknownError,
  TimeoutError)